# Proving homeomorphisms

Tags: metric-spaces

I came across this practice question, which seems rather simple - but I am wondering if I am not understanding something completely.

If I were to define an explicit homeomorphism to demonstrate that any two arbitrary circles are homeomorphic in $\mathbb{R}^2$ - can a simple one simply be defined by a radial projection from the origin from one circle to another?

Comment: If they both have the origin in therir inside, yes

Comment: If the radii are not equal, make an homothetic transformation. If they are, make a translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two circles, $C_1$ and $C_2,$ with respective radii $r_1$ and $r_2.$. Without loss of generality, suppose $r_1\le r_2.$ Let $C_1'$ and $C_2'$ be the circles' respective translations to circles centered at the origin. Then radial projection will allow you to map $C_1'$ to $C_2'.$

Can you put the pieces together to construct a formula that gives an explicit homeomorphism $C_1\to C_2$? (Note: this formula should even work when $r_1>r_2$.)

Comment: Thanks - that was along the lines of what I was thinking. But I am struggling a bit with constructing an explicit mapping. Is there anything wrong simply defining the mapping as $f(r_{1}cos\theta,r_{1}sin\theta) = (r_{2}cos\theta,r_{2}sin\theta)$, this is a bijective, continuous mapping isn't it?

Comment: That will give you the mapping $C_1'\to C_2'.$ There's nothing wrong with it--it's a crucial ingredient--but it doesn't do the job on its own.

Comment: I suppose I have then shown an explicit homeomorphism for any two arbitrary circles when translated to be centered at the origin. So I need to show that the original circles are homeomorphic as well...how would I go about doing that from here? Thanks for any hints/advice you can give me.

Comment: Consider $C_1\to C_1'\to C_2'\to C_2.$

Comment: Thank you for your help. Taking your advice, for any arbitrary circle, say $C_1 = (a+r_{1}cos\theta,b+r_{1}sin\theta)$, we can translate this to the origin by $f(a+r_{1}cos\theta,b+r_{1}sin\theta)= (r_{1}cos\theta,r_{1}sin\theta) =C_{1}'$, which is a homeomorphism, since it is a translation, so $C_1 \cong C_{1}'$ and the same can be done with $C_2$. Then with the function described above $\implies C_1 \cong C_{1}' \cong C_{2}' \cong C_{2}$. This seems quite simple - but am I missing anything?

Comment: That's pretty much it! As long as you know that (valid) compositions of homeomorphisms are again homeomorphism, you're done!